# How can I use std::future without using std::async?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, asynchronous, future

I'm using two `boost::interprocess::message_queue` for inter process communication. One is for sending commands, another for receiving answers. When I'm sending command I'm creating a `std::promise` which return a `std::future` object to the caller of my function

```
std::shared_future<bool> PluginMQAdapter::exec(const std::string& exec_str) const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    promise_queue.push(std::make_shared<std::promise<bool> >());
    need_exec_queue.push(exec_str);

    return promise_queue.back()->get_future();
}
```

And after receiving the result

```
int number = 0;
if(recv_mq->try_receive(&number, sizeof(number), recvd_size, priority) && !promise_queue.empty())
{
    promise_queue.front()->set_value(number != 0);
    promise_queue.pop();
}
```

How can I poll `std::future` in this case? `wait_for` and `wait_until` are not working 'cause the _Running field of `future` is set to false and as so the state of `future` is always deferred. How can I use `std::future` without using `std::async`?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but you're polling a std::shared_future, not a std::future here.

Comment: Just rereading the question, was your actual issue that `wait_for` and `wait_until` are returning `future_status::deferred` and you're checking for `future_status::timeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround with `boost::shared_future`

```
auto result = exec(exec_str);
const unsigned int wait_msec = 10, max_wait_msec = 5000;
unsigned int i = 0;
while(!result.is_ready() && i < max_wait_msec)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(wait_msec));
    i += wait_msec;
}
if(result.is_ready())
    return result.get();
```

What was the problem to make it standard?!

And shorter version works as well

```
boost::future_status ok = result.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(max_wait_msec));
if((ok == boost::future_status::ready))
    return result.get();
```

Comment: The `std` version also has `wait_for` and `future_status`.

Comment: I have. I don't understand how using `wait_for` from boost:shared_future is different from using `wait_for` in std::future. Both should be returning deferred until the promise gets set. Or in other words, did
````
std::future_status ok = result.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(max_wait_msec));
if((ok == std::future_status::ready))
    return result.get();
````
not work?

Comment: If it's just 'is_ready' you're looking for, then that was missing from std::future. It's added in C++17, but (wait_for(0) == future_status::ready) is the workaround.

Comment: If I remember right std::future is only set by std::async.

Comment: A std::future is also set by set::promise::set_value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 (it's not mentioned in the question), then this turns out to be a bug in the implementation, fixed in Visual Studio 2013. Quoting from http://cpprocks.com/44-c11-bugs-fixed-in-visual-studio-2013/

> ### Useless wait functions in a future provided by promise
>
> There was a significant downside to using a future provided by a promise. Due to a bug in Visual Studio 2012, the `wait_for` and `wait_until` methods of such `future` objects returned `future_status::deferred` instead of `future_status::timeout` or `future_status::ready`, rendering these methods useless.